# Cannot fill width of screen with camera view

Tags: java, android, android-studio

As you can see in the picture below, there are white bars on each side of the camera preview.

[image: Faulty app]

Padding and margins do not work, and I cannot find anything that make it a programmatically defined width. [Though, if it was programmatically defined, it'd be found here.](https://github.com/LivotovLabs/CamView)

My XMLs are all defaults of the Navigation Drawer Activity preset except this one below:

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<eu.livotov.labs.android.camview.ScannerLiveView
    android:id="@+id/camview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

I've attempted to change everything I could think of, but I am not necessarily good at UI

Comment: Try to set `android:layout_margin="0dp"` or/and `android:padding="0dp"`. If your `ScannerListView has configured a padding or margin inside its layout, doing this you are removing it. Also, `fill_parent` is deprecated, use `match_parent` instead.

Comment: @MarcEstrada Unfortunately that did not fix the formatting :/

Comment: :( try setting a background color to the cam view to see if it's filling all screen.

Comment: I couldn't find any information about how to do that. Would you mind explaining? Sorry to bother. @marcestrada

Comment: Add an atribute like that: `android:background="#ff0000"` (this is red).

Comment: OH! I see what you mean now. Thank you. I will try shortly.

Comment: @MarcEstrada sorry to bother again, I just wanted to see if you had any more advice. I added a background color and it changes the color of the side bars, so the view is stretched to the correct width, but the camera defaults to this size for some odd reason. Changing the width does not seem to affect it.

Comment: Are you using a library to show this cam view? In affirmative case, tell me which one.

Comment: It is linked in the post below the picture

Comment: Try removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Comment: Or try also to remove `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"` and `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`

Comment: None of that worked, but I just made the background black to hide the margins for now. I've spent too long working on the UI and I'll eventually come back to it. I appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem sir :)

Comment: Just wanted to update and say that the problem was partially due to the library I was using to make the camera easier to control and manage. I switched to one released by Google a month or two after I made this post and that solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution:

Don't use `eu.livotov.labs.android.camview.ScannerLiveView`

I instead switched to `com.google.android.cameraview.CameraView`, which is a library you can find on [Github](https://github.com/google/cameraview).

I will soon be switching to [Jetpack CameraX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera) now that Google is finally adding higher level support to their camera API.